# Generating Main content nodes based on SQL data (associated with users)

Tags: 7, nodes, database

This is the first fully fledged website outside of a blog that I've ever configured, so please forgive any glaring errors I make in my logic.

My website is a ranking website: people create a profile for their website with an image, title and description, and users (who have separate 'voter' profiles) vote based on the website they visit. Voter and Websites are distinguished by a field.

All of the other profile details (image, desc ect.) are also stored in fields, and votes are recorded with an SQL table.

My website then displays the image and description of each website, in order of descending number of votes. (a ranking)

---

This is where I encounter my issue. In order to display these values properly (scrolling through pages) I need to display them as nodes. I have no idea how to generate these nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to display as nodes here: the website profiles?  Are they not nodes already?

Comment: Website profiles would probably work, although I've got no idea if it's possible. I can't find a relevant tutorial.

Comment: I'm still not sure I know what you want to display... :)

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood about the problem you are facing, i believe its advised using the content type for profile as well as the votes. Here is the CCK field to use the vote field. 
https://www.drupal.org/project/rate
It would be very easy for you to create view if all fields are part of content types.